# Evaluating a quadratic form with an inverse of a sparse PD matrix, comparison between using the inverse vs using a Cholseky decomposition

Tags: computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have the following quadratic form I need to evaluate:

$x^T A^{-1} y$, where $A$ is a sparse positive definite matrix, $x, y$ are sparse vectors.

Now assume that I am given **for free** both $A^{-1}$ and the Cholesky decomposition $A = L D L^T$. I understand that it be faster to evaluate $x^T A^{-1} y$ using a Cholseky decomposition, rather than directly.

Can anyone relate to the computational complexity (+ references) of each alternative?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The "direct" approach requires about $O(n^2)$ operations while using Cholesky gives $O(nk)$, where $n$ is the size of $A$ and $k$ is the maximum number of nonzeros in the rows of $L$. Even if you had $A^{-1}$ for free, it would almost certainly be a dense matrix making the first approach very likely to be much less efficient if you can compute a Cholesky factorization with low fill-in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.